# Vertx unit test never finishes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, reactive-programming, vert.x

I have a vertx unit test with vertx version 3.3.2 and JUnit version 4.12.
The following unit test never finishes:

```
@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeVerticleTest {

    private Vertx vertx;

    @Before
    public void before(TestContext context) {
        vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(SomeVerticle.class.getName(), r -> context.asyncAssertSuccess()); // problem is in this line, see answer for solution!
    }

    @Test
    public void doStuff(TestContext context) {
        String encodedMessage = Json.encode("myMessage");
        Async async = context.async();
        vertx.eventBus().send("someVerticle", encodedMessage, asyncResult -> {
            // some context.asserts on the message reply
            async.complete(); // this line is executed, I can see it in the debugger
        });
    }
}
```

The test itself runs fine, the message is sent, correctly processed by the handler in `SomeVerticle` and the reply is created and sent correctly.

But: Although the method `doStuff` is executed and its success is published to the `Async` object, the test just runs forever, it never ends. This can be verified by adding an after-test method, annotated with `@After` which is never executed.

I have tried to find the error for two hours now, but I simply don't know what exactly the problem might be, so I would be happy about any assistance.

**[update]**
After two minutes, the test fails with a timeout.

**[update 2]**
I found the problem and put it into a separate answer.

Comment: Where is it blocking?

Comment: It executes the async.complete() line and after that, the process just never finishes. In IntelliJ the test process never finishes, when running through maven it also never finishes. There is no blocking code - at least not in my classes - in which the process hangs.

Comment: Is it exiting your test method?  Put a `System.out.println` after `vertx.eventBus().send(...)` see if it ever gets there.

Comment: Yes, it does exit the test method, I can did what you recommend ;-)

Comment: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_causing_vert_x_to_exit

Comment: I fear that won't work once I add more tests. Where would I put that `.close()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is not within the actual testing method, but in the setup.

The following statement does NOT complete:

```
vertx.deployVerticle(SomeVerticle.class.getName(), r -> context.asyncAssertSuccess());
```

To get it actually working, we need to use the `Async` construct as mentioned in the docs [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_asynchronous_testing) and [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_asynchronous_assertions).

A correct statement which leads to a working test is as follows:

```
vertx.deployVerticle(SomeVerticle.class.getName(), context.asyncAssertSuccess()); // note the missing r->
```

I hope this answer helps someone being stuck with a similar problem.